# This name doesn't exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is a basic coding question but I am learning on the job and trying to figure out the parameter this method is looking for, because when I leave it blank it seems to tell me it is looking for "position", which is what I have in there. This is referring to the `OnTradeCalledBack` and `OnPositionCalledBack` methods.

This is the error I get when leaving the parameter blank:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal       parameter 'position' of 'SocketServer.AsynchronousSocketListener.MyPositionCallBackEventHandler'  SocketServer

Here is the code:

```
public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    public AsynchronousSocketListener(int port)
    {
    }

    //Need to create a delagate to handle the positions and trade information.
    public delegate void MyPositionCallBackEventHandler(TposPositionCallback position);
    public delegate void MyTradeCallBackEventHandler(TposTradeCallback trade);

    //Indicates something has happened and finished.
    //Event defined here, based on delegate

    public event MyPositionCallBackEventHandler PositionCalledBack;
    public event MyTradeCallBackEventHandler TradeCalledBack;

    //Raise the Event, need a method to do this.
    //Responsible for notifying subscribers

    protected virtual void OnPositionCalledBack()
    {
        //need to fix this, just added local to avoid error
        //TposPositionCallback position = null;
        if (PositionCalledBack != null)
            PositionCalledBack(position);
    }

    protected virtual void OnTradeCalledBack()
    {
        //need to fix this, just added local to avoid error
        //TposTradeCallback trade = null;
        if (TradeCalledBack != null)
            TradeCalledBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of your 'position' variable and where is it defined?

Comment: public delegate void MyPositionCallBackEventHandler(TposPositionCallback position);

Comment: No, what is the type of `position` in the method `OnPositionCalledBack` and where is it defined? Is what @CathalMF was asking I think.

Comment: @JP Hochbaum - No in the OnPositionCalledBack() method you have a 'position' variable used which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @CathalMF I think that is the local variable the OP added in the commented out code but just forgot to remove it in this code for demonstrations sake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into the code `TradeCalledBack` is an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) with a signature of:

```
public event MyTradeCallBackEventHandler TradeCalledBack;
```

Therefore `TradeCalledBack` will need to have the parameters passed to it that are defined in the `MyTradeCallBackEventHandler` which is a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173171.aspx) with a signature of:

```
public delegate void MyTradeCallBackEventHandler(TposTradeCallback trade);
```

Therefore `TradeCalledBack` needs to have a variable of type `TposTradeCallback` passed into it.

To overcome the error you can pass null into the method as such:

```
TradeCalledBack(null);
```

or change the whole method to something like the following and pass the variable into it:

```
protected virtual void OnTradeCalledBack(TposTradeCallback trade)
{
    if (TradeCalledBack != null)
    {
        TradeCalledBack(trade);
    }
}
```

Following the logic here you can do similar changes for `OnPositionCalledBack`.

Comment: Yep, knew it was something basic, I blame my massive head cold for missing this. Thanks!

Comment: @JPHochbaum Also note that the comments in the code actually tell you what you need to look for, they're describing what is happening throughout the code. So if you get stuck again just read through them carefully.

Answer (score 0):

just change the definition to

```
public delegate void MyPositionCallBackEventHandler(TposPositionCallback position = null);
```

which passes null as default if no parameter is supplied